# Cancel Button Redirect using "More Buttons" Module with Drupal 7

Tags: redirect, button, drupal-7, forums

Alright, firstly, I love this module (More Buttons Module, v7.x-1.0-beta1) and it's working pretty good for me in most cases, but I have a scenario that it isn't quite doing what I need.

I'm using the Drupal 7 Forums, and when I go to create a new topic, it is added from /node/add/forum/133 (for example) -- Then when I hit cancel (from "More Buttons" module, of course) it redirects me to /node/add -- which I don't want at all, and don't want visitors to be able to get to even.

Ideally, I would get redirected back to where I first came from to initiate the New Topic in the forum, for example, /forums/general-discussion, then I hit "New Topic" and it takes you to the Add New Forum Post page, where if I hit cancel, I'd love to go back to /forums/general-discussion, not /node/add page.

Is that doable?

Comment: I know it's a bit late to answer but I don't think the module is maintained any more unfortunately. I've found some problems too and I hope somebody might take it on (see also https://drupal.org/node/1416844#comment-8393077).